# Computing the angle of three points

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have three points, each point has a `Bar_Index and Value`.
I am trying to compute the angle between the tree points in a way that point `C` is the one in the center  (on the top in the fig) and `1` and `2` are the ones on the sides (left and right of point C).
I am not sure why my computed angle in degree is so small, based on the figure it should be much larger (more than 20 degree).Does anyone know what I am missing?
Here is the code,

```
Cx = bar_index_0
Cy = Value_0

P0x = bar_index_1
P0y = Value_1

P1x = bar_index_2
P1y = Value_2

P0C = math.sqrt(math.pow((P0x-Cx),2)+math.pow((P0y-Cy),2))
P1C = math.sqrt(math.pow((P1x-Cx),2)+math.pow((P1y-Cy),2))
P0P1 = math.sqrt(math.pow((P1x-P0x),2)+math.pow((P1y-P0y),2))

top = (P1C*P1C + P0C*P0C - P0P1*P0P1)
down = 2*P1C*P0C
Angle = (math.todegrees(math.acos(top/down)))
```

Also, if anyone has a better suggestion to compute the three angles inside the triangle I will be happy to hear it.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In vector math, the angle is ((p0-C) dot (p1-C)) / (len(p0-C)*len(p1-C)).
So, try:

```
P0Cx = P0x-Cx
P0Cy = P0y-Cy
P1Cx = P1x-Cx
P1Cy = P1y-Cy
dot = P0Cx*p1Cx + P0Cy*P1Cy
div = P0C*P1C
angle = math.acos(dot/div)
```